# ¿Como puedo enviar dos objeto por medio ajax a un web api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Necesito enviar dos objeto a los metodos post y update  a una web Api, trabajo con c#, webapi, mvc. No lo está tomando.

```
var album = {
    nombre: "PowerAge",
    Fecha: "011/10/1979"
}
var user = {
    Name: "Rick"
    area: "operaciones"
}

$.ajax(
{
    url: "samples/PostAlbum",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ album: album, user: user }),
     success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

Api

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult PostAlbum(album item, user itemuser)
{

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes. Por favor describe más de tu problema, muestra el código que tienes, lo que has intentado para resolverlo y dónde te has atascado. De esta manera será más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: No deberías necesitar el `JSON.stringify()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta usando

```
$.ajax(
{
   url: "samples/PostAlbum",
   type: "POST",
   contentType: "application/json",
   data: { item: album, itemuser: user },
   success: function (result) {
       alert(result);
    }
});
```

Como observaras en el json que envías como `data` debe coincidir con los parámetros del `webapi`,

```
data: { item: album, itemuser: user },
```

por eso definí `item` y `itemuser` que coinciden con los parámetros del action que invocas.

---

Por otro lado si es webapi la url debería ser: `api/samples`

Definir el action no es necesario porque con el verbo del `http` alcanza. Esto aplica si es un controller que hereda de `ApiController`, en cambio si se trata de controller simple deberías usar:

```
url: '@Url.Action("PostAlbum")',
```

dejas que `@Url.Action()` desde la view sea quien defina la url.